# Display different address with .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have tried several methods but wouldn't work. I have a page that displays as:

`http://www.site.com/page?page=about-us`

I wish to have the page url displayed as:

`http://www.site.com/page/about-us`

Where "about-us" is the parameter sent to "page.php"

Is this possible with htaccess?

Comment: Could you please state how it can be done? Thanks

Comment: Just to be curious. What forces you to write an .htaccess file to solve this problem ? Are you restricted from editing Apache's configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to tell Apache that you are going to rewrite by:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
```

Then use the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.+) /page?page=$ [NC]
```

Be careful with just copying the text.The difference between Windows and Linux end of lines can sometimes give an error 500. Windows use CR LF and Linux only LF

If you want to know more about how it works:
http://corz.org/server/tricks/htaccess2.php